# Postgresql: detecting which foreign key triggered the "on before delete" trigger

Tags: postgresql

Let `T` be a table with two columns: `a` and `b`, which reference, respectively, to tables `A` and `B`. Such references are of type "delete cascade", so if a row from `A` or `B` is deleted, the row in `T` which matches the origin reference will be also deleted.

Now, I want to set a trigger "on before delete row" on `T`: is there any way to detect which of the reference triggered the row deletion in `T`? In other words: can I know if the trigger was triggered by cascading from `A` or from `B`?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

OK, I've simplified the problem. I have the following tables:

**users**:

- id: integer SERIAL primary key
- name: character varying(128)

**validatorchains**:

- id: integer SERIAL primary key
- name: character varying(128)

**validatorchainslinks**:

- chain: integer foreign key validatorchains.id on delete cascade
- user:  integer foreign key users.id on delete cascade
- next:  integer foreign key users.id on delete set null
- prev:  integer foreign key users.id on delete set null

The code of my "on before delete" trigger on `validatorchainslinks` is:

```
BEGIN   
   UPDATE validatorchainslinks SET next = OLD.next WHERE next = OLD.user;
   UPDATE validatorchainslinks SET prev = OLD.prev WHERE prev = OLD.user;
   RETURN OLD;
END;
```

So, the purpose is to create a linked list of users that can validate some sort of operation. In order to validate the operation, all users in the chain must agree. The problem arises when maintaining the linked list when a user is deleted. The trigger code above successfully relinks the elements of the chain. But, what happens if the deletion is triggered by deleting a row in `validatorchains`? I don't want the trigger to do the UPDATE stuff, but skip it and let the system delete all the rows that reference to the corresponding validator chain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this a step to solving a larger problem? We might do better if we know what the overall goal is - are you trying to enforce some higher level integrity constraint?

Comment: Well, the larger problem is quite complex to describe, and I've found alternatives to solve it. However I came across with this case and I wanted to know if there was a way to know what constraint or column triggered the deletion.

Comment: In theory, you can query the referenced tables to check the referenced row is still there if you use `AFTER` triggers. But no, nothing direct with `BEFORE` triggers. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html Maybe worth describing the larger problem.

Comment: I've updated the question in order to give a general idea of what I'm looking for. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Do you need `next` and `prev` for other reasons and/or are they checked for consistency? Why can you not have e.g. just a sequence number to indicate the order of users within each chain?

Comment: OMG... I didn't think about this! A sequence number would make things easier! I think I don't need next/prev for consistency, so thank you very much! Please, write your comment as a reply.

Comment: @Claudix: do you even insert users into the middle of a chain? Sequence numbers would make it harder. Also, why don't you just leave the chain as is, and make the validation code just skip the missing links, not testing validation for the records with no entry in `users`?

Comment: @Quassnoi - that's why I usually recommend `float` for such numbers rather than `int`, but nobody else ever seems to buy that it means the renumberings are a rare event - provided you start off assigning integers and then whenever you want to insert between two existing rows, you just average their values.

Comment: @Quassnoi, in my case it's not a problem because any chain manipulation is completely comitted to the database (i.e. the chain is retrieved, modified, and then fully written back to the database, so numbers can be regenerated).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a little work-around.

Since PG does not give you any relevant information in the trigger function that fires on the cascaded `DELETE` (in `validatorchainslinks`) you should record this information somewhere, immediately prior to the foreign record (in `users`or `validatorchains`) being deleted. So you can write a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger that updates all records in `validatorchainslinks` with a value that you can then check in the trigger function of the latter table. This would require you to add a field to the table of course.

Alternatively, you can create a separate table that lists records from tables that are about to be deleted and any trigger function can then review that information. Write that table in a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger and remove the record in an `AFTER DELETE` trigger on the same table. This would be the more elegant solution if the same pattern (cascaded deletes) happens among multiple tables.

Cascaded deletes happen in a single transaction so you should be protected from race conditions.

Comment: Although I found the way to solve my problem without the need of what I initially asked, this is a very interesting approach. I will bookmark it for possible future applications. Thank you!